# How to get world countries borders in term of coordinates?

Tags: ios, maps, mapkit

How to get world countries borders in term of array of coordinates?
I would like to draw countries overlays in the world map using Mapkit of IOS.

Answer (score 0):

Id say your best bet is finding a Google maps KML File which is basically XML and then iterating through and putting it in your own format. As infact I was just about to do something like this for my own project (not IOS), got any format in mind for it and ill be able to give you a version too? Although I personally am not sure if there's any sort of built in method for you to do it (perhaps ask on IOS developers forums).